# Create ranges out of rows VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have multiple rows which are sometimes in order and sometimes not.
Out of rows which are in order, I would need to create a range, which are not in order just to copy the number.

The thing is, the most rows in order can be even 20.

For example cells:
1
3
5
6
7
8
9
10
13
14
15

There would be:
1
3
5-10
13-15

Is it possible to code it?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible!

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve. You say "create range" -- do you mean a VBA range, for use in some other piece of code? Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Range using VBA, like in the example. If you have 4 numbers in a row, 3 4 5 6 you would get a result 3-6. So range in this meaning, from 3 until 6. Basically, code would evaluate if next cell in rows is +1, if yes, it evaluates next cell whether it is +1, if yes, evaluate next one. If not, it would take first number where it starts to increase +1 and last one when there is no +1, and would create a range out of it in this example 3-6.

Comment: So far I have almost nothing, in VBA I know just some basics - loops, if, never did something like this and cannot code it, I can`t find some examples how to do it neither :( Therefore I would need help

Comment: Which column is this in? And do you need to store each range specifically? What do you want to do with the ranges afterwards?

Comment: Data are from ERP database, ranges are for defining security rules. The result contains all possible range which are not used in system yet. Basically the reason of usage is not so important, I would need just a code, because there are zillions of tables for many countries and manually it would be almost not possible to define it.

Comment: Yes each range would be necessary specifically, but it`s not important as then is just possible to create unique list easily.

Comment: @bennes If I understood this correctly, you are not talking about "ranges" in Excel terminology, but you simply want your first table to write into your second table, am I right?

Comment: yes exactly. sorry for wrong terminology, english is not my native language. And Nan Avan Illai`s solution was correct and what I`ve needed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data starts with A1.... and

required results will be printed at C column.

Try with below code

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, incre As Long
    Dim startno As Variant
    Dim endno As Variant
    incre = 1
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If Cells(i, 1) = (Cells(i + 1, 1) - 1) Then
            startno = Cells(i, 1)
            Do While Cells(i, 1) = (Cells(i + 1, 1) - 1)
                endno = Cells(i + 1, 1)
                i = i + 1
            Loop
            Cells(incre, 3) = "'" & startno & "-" & endno
            incre = incre + 1
        Else
            Cells(incre, 3) = Cells(i, 1)
            incre = incre + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect Nan Avan Illai, that was exactly what I needed :)  Thank you

Comment: Please mark it as solution by clicking the tick symbol

Comment: it tells me I need reputation 15 to mark it :( I have only 11 currently

Answer (score 0):

if you want the *address* of all consecutive ranges you could use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim rangeStrng As String

    With Worksheets("MyRowsSheet") '<--| change "MyRowsSheet" with your actual sheet name
        rangeStrng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas.Parent.Address(False, False)
    End With
End Sub
```

if you want only the *rows* range then you could use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main2()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rowsRangeStrng As String

    With Worksheets("MyRowsSheet") '<--| change "MyRowsSheet" with your actual sheet name
        For Each rng In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas
            If rng.Rows.Count = 1 Then
                rowsRangeStrng = rowsRangeStrng & rng.Rows(1).Row & ","
            Else
                rowsRangeStrng = rowsRangeStrng & rng.Rows(1).Row & "-" & rng.Rows(rng.Rows.Count).Row & ","
            End If
        Next rng
    End With
    If rowsRangeStrng <> "" Then rowsRangeStrng = Left(rowsRangeStrng, Len(rowsRangeStrng) - 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are not looking to address a range, but rather want an output table. This code below should provide you with just that. My input numbers are in column A, and the output is in column B.

```
Sub sequentials()

Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim tmpRowA, tmpRowB As Integer
Dim seq() As Long

Dim frA, frB, lrA As Integer       'firstrow col A, col B, lastrow of data


    Set tws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    frA = 2
    frB = 2

    lrA = tws.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row


    'Input in column A, Output in column B
    'Headers in Row 1

    ReDim seq(0 To lrA - 1)

    seq(0) = -2
    seq(1) = tws.Range("A" & frA).Value

    tmpRowA = frA
    tmpRowB = frB

    tws.Range("B" & frB & ":B" & lrA).NumberFormat = "@"

    For r = frA + 1 To lrA

    If r = 23 Then
        r = 23
    End If

        With tws

            seq(r - 1) = .Range("A" & r).Value

            If seq(r - 1) = seq(r - 2) + 1 Then
                If r = lrA Then
                    .Range("B" & tmpRowB).Value = .Range("A" & tmpRowA - 1).Value & "-" & seq(r - 1)
                End If
            Else
                If seq(r - 2) = seq(r - 3) + 1 Then
                    .Range("B" & tmpRowB).Value = .Range("A" & tmpRowA - 1).Value & "-" & seq(r - 2)
                Else
                    .Range("B" & tmpRowB).Value = seq(r - 2)
                End If
                tmpRowB = tmpRowB + 1
                tmpRowA = r + 1

                If r = lrA Then
                    .Range("B" & tmpRowB).Value = seq(r - 1)
                End If

            End If

        End With

    Next r


End Sub
```

Proof of concept:

[image: Proof of Concept]